# Double left-alignment in a big bracket

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to write 2 lines of inequalities contained in a big bracket. Thus I use `\left\{` and `\right.` Additionally, I hope to write 2 inequalities in one line (i.e. 2 "<" symbol), and there needs 2 left alignment respectively.

However, the output of following code always contains a huge blank before the second "<" in each line. I'm wondering how to eliminate that blank.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[allow-number-unit-breaks]{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\left\{\begin{aligned}
-4&< |x_1| &&< -2\\
-4&< |x_2| &&< -2
\end{aligned}\right.$
\end{document}
```

Here's the visual output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands (but only the relevant ones), ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @SandyG Thanks for the instruction. As an amateur, I wonder if it works now after my editing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want the big space before the `<`, use `alignedat*`.  Also, the arrangement of packages could be more compact: `mathtools` (loads `amsmath`), `amssymb` (loads `amsfonts`), then `amsthm`.  Otherwise, group related packages (e.g. all fonts, all tables).

Comment: Why not use the `cases` environment?

Comment: @barbarabeeton it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Stephen -- `\cases` is good for the brace, but it doesn't get rid of the spacing problem.